# "The term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program error" shows up every time I open powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Every time I open powershell the error

> The term 'I' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program shows up. How do I fix this problem?

[image]

I have tried to search for this error on the internet but it seems that most of the times the error appears after running a script

Comment: Debug your profile!  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Looks like it tries to interpret the first letter of a command as a whole command. Might that be a wrong encoding or the script file?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely to be in your Profile script.  The profile script is run when Powershell starts.  If you had, for example, a profile script containing the single letter "l",  you would get an error like the one you report.

You can learn more about Profile files in the [About Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3) topic.

You can try starting powershell with the -noprofile parameter in order to skip profile processing.  If this makes the problem go away,  that would confirm the suspicion that a defective profile script is causing the error.
 
There are four possible profile files outlined in the help topic referenced above.  You may have to open all four in order to find the source of the error.  You may have to access the powershell files logged in with administrator privileges.

If this is the source of the problem, you know what to do.

As to where a rogue profile script might have come from, I haven't a clue.